# How to use lags of independent variables in (non)linear panel data models with fixed effects?

Tags: r, regression, mathematical-statistics, econometrics, panel-data

I would like to estimate a fixed effect model:

$EDT_{it} =\alpha_i +\sum_{l=1}^{n} \beta GDPW_{it-n}+ \gamma OIL_{it}+\zeta B_{t} + u_{it}$ 
where $\alpha_i$ are the individual fixed effects and $\zeta B_{t}$ are time fixed effects.

Im not sure about the following:

Assuming that only regressor GDPW has an effect on y over time rather than all at once (instantaneous)

1. Is it a correct practise to run lags from 1 to 3 $\sum_{l=1}^{3} \beta GDPW_{it-3}$ such in cases of distributed-lag models and report them all coeffients or do I have to choose just one lag and stick with it?
2. And is it legitimate to estimate the equation with multiple lags for nonlinear fixed effects such as negative binomial?

Get example:

```
\###########################################################

\

library(plm) # linear panel models
library(pglm) # nonlinear panel models
options(scipen=999)

\#Getting the data

df <- read.csv("http://faculty.washington.edu/cadolph/panEssex/democracy.csv",header=TRUE,na.strings=".")


\## Do lags and manipulation
lag1 <- function(x) {
GDPW <- ts(x$GDPW, start = x$YEAR[1])
idx <- seq(length = length(GDPW))
GDPW <- cbind(GDPW, GDPW.lag1 = lag(GDPW, -1))[idx,]
cbind(x, GDPW)
} 
lag2 <- function(x) {
GDPW <- ts(x$GDPW, start = x$YEAR[1])
idx <- seq(length = length(GDPW))
GDPW <- cbind(GDPW, GDPW.lag2 = lag(GDPW, -2))[idx,]
cbind(x, GDPW)
} 
lag3 <- function(x) {
GDPW <- ts(x$GDPW, start = x$YEAR[1])
idx <- seq(length = length(GDPW))
GDPW <- cbind(GDPW, GDPW.lag3 = lag(GDPW, -3))[idx,]
cbind(x, GDPW)
} 
lag1 <- do.call("rbind", by(df, df$COUNTRY, lag1))
lag2 <- do.call("rbind", by(df, df$COUNTRY, lag2)) 
lag3 <- do.call("rbind", by(df, df$COUNTRY, lag3)) 

# cbind all together
 selectdata <- na.omit(cbind(df$COUNTRY,
                        df$CTYNAME,
                        df$YEAR,
                        df$GDPW,
                        df$EDT,
                        df$REG,
                        df$OIL,
                        lag1$GDPW.lag1,
                        lag2$GDPW.lag2,
                        lag3$GDPW.lag3))

 selectdata <- as.data.frame(selectdata)
 names(selectdata) <-    c("COUNTRY","CTYNAME","YEAR","GDPW","EDT","REG","OIL","lag1",
                      "lag2","lag3")

select <- selectdata[,-c(1,2)]
# change data type
indx <- sapply(select, is.factor)
select[indx] <- lapply(select[indx], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
# bind all together
selectdata <- cbind(selectdata[,c(1,2)],select)



\# First for the linear case, assuming EDT is count data

fixed.plm <- plm(sqrt(EDT) ~ GDPW+OIL+lag1+lag2+lag3, data=selectdata,       index=c("COUNTRY", "YEAR"), model="within")
summary(fixed.plm)
fixed.pglm <- pglm(EDT ~ GDPW+OIL+lag1+lag2+lag3, data=selectdata, family = 'negbin', index=c("COUNTRY", "YEAR"), model="within")
summary(fixed.plm)
\###########################################################
```